# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 with json server

Tags: javascript, json, axios

hello im want create method post api with axios and post data to json-server,but im running my code error connection,example mycode :

```
const axios = require('axios')
function addApi(){
   const url = axios.post('http:localhost:3000/posts,{
                 "id" : 5,
                 "name" : "lorem"
              }).then((result) => {
                    console.log('sukses post to json server ' + 
                    result.data)    
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
  return url
}
addApi()
```

and im run this code  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: do you have a web server running on your machine at port 3000?

Comment: you have an error in code. You did not close url string. After /posts should go '

Comment: hmm solve for this case,thanks
im running server and execute my program in separate